# How to draw a multiple line chart using plotly_express?

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I need to create a line chart from multiple columns of a dataframe. In pandas, you can draw a multiple line chart using a code as follows:

```py
df.plot(x='date', y=['sessions', 'cost'], figsize=(20,10), grid=True)
```

How can this be done using plotly_express?

Comment: Please share if you find a way :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With [version 4.8  of Plotly.py](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-8-plotly-express-support-for-wide-and-mixed-form-data-plus-a-pandas-backend/40048/1), the code in the original question is now supported almost unmodified:

```py
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df.plot(x='date', y=['sessions', 'cost'])
```

---

*Previous answer, as of July 2019*

For this example, you could prepare the data slightly differently.

```
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='date', value_vars=['sessions', 'cost'])
```

If you transpose/melt your columns (sessions, cost) into additional rows, then you can specify the new column 'variable' to partition by in the color parameter.

```
px.line(df_melt, x='date' , y='value' , color='variable')
```

[Example plotly_express output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfyuf.png)

Comment: what does 'variable' mean in the 'color' argument ?

Answer (score 8):

With newer versions of plotly, all you need is:

```
df.plot()
```

As long as you remember to set [pandas plotting backend to plotly](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/):

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

From here you can easily adjust your plot to your liking, for example setting the theme:

```
df.plot(template='plotly_dark')
```

#### Plot with dark theme:

[image]

One particularly awesome feature with newer versions of plotly is that you no longer have to worry whether your pandas dataframe is of a [wide or long format](https://medium.com/plotly/beyond-tidy-plotly-express-now-accepts-wide-form-and-mixed-form-data-bdc3e054f891). Either way, all you need is `df.plot()`. Check out the details in the snippet below.

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# settings
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

# sample dataframe of a wide format
np.random.seed(4); cols = list('abc')
X = np.random.randn(50,len(cols))  
df=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=cols)
df.iloc[0]=0; df=df.cumsum()

# plotly figure
df.plot(template = 'plotly_dark')
```

---

#### Answer for older versions:

I would highly suggest using `iplot()` instead if you'd like to use plotly in a Jupyter Notebook for example:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# Random data using cufflinks
df1 = cf.datagen.lines()
df2 = cf.datagen.lines()
df3 = cf.datagen.lines()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_index = True, right_index = True)
df = pd.merge(df, df3, how='left',left_index = True, right_index = True)

fig = df1.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter',xTitle='Dates',yTitle='Returns',title='Returns')
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks vestland for your help. Cufflinks is a very helpful library for charting plotly graphs directly in the pandas dataframes. But, I'm still wondrering if there is a way to do the same one-liner code using plotly express.

Comment: That does not work. ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead. And then it want some login info.

Comment: @vestland is there any wat to control the x axis labels in this case?

Comment: @Reut Le'ts talk in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222912/room-for-vestland-and-reut)

Comment: @Reut Just click the link

Comment: @vestland when I use `df.plot(template='plotly_dark')` I get a ValueError cannot process wide-form data with columns of different types

Comment: @vestland x axis is datetime and the y axis is float

Answer (score 3):

Its also worth pointing out you can combine plotly express with graph_objs. This is a good route when the lines have different x points.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# data set 1
x = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
y = x

# data set 2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x*0.5, y]), columns=["x", "y"])

fig = go.Figure(px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

fig.show()
```