# Python: how to plot data coming from different excel sheets in the same chart

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plotly, openpyxl

I need to create an interactive chart on python taking data from different sheets of an Excel file. I tried to create a for loop to take data from all the sheets automatically, but I manage to graph only data coming from the last sheet of the file.
I also would like to create a legend with the names of the sheets where data come from. This is my code, can you help me improving it?

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os, os.path
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

output_data2=r'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Vibration data analysis'

wb=xl.load_workbook(os.path.join(output_data2, "RMS Comparison.xlsx"))
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    if sheet.title != 'Graph':
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(output_data2, "RMS Comparison.xlsx"),sheet_name=sheet.title)
        fig = px.line(df, x='Unnamed: 0', y='Unnamed: 2')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Try to indent `fig.show()`. I believe that your code might work, but it only shows the last plot since it is outside of the `for-loop`.

Comment: Thanks, I indented it but it creates different charts, one for each sheet of the Excel file, while I need to have all data shown in the same graph in order to compare them..

Comment: if you want to combine all dataframe to one, which you then want to print try this: After your have created the indvidual `df` write a line in which you append this `df` to `df_list` (which you need to create first). Then as soon as your loop is done concat all the `df` within this list by this line: `df_final = pd.concat(df_list)`. This `df_final` could then be used to create a graph based on the columns of your final dataframe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822042/how-to-draw-a-multiple-line-chart-using-plotly-express).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated a workbook to demonstrate **plotly** code
- create a figure, then add a line per worksheet

```
import openpyxl as xl
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("RMS Comparison.xlsx")

# create an Excel with multiple sheets
with pd.ExcelWriter(f) as writer: 
    for s in "ABCDEF":
        pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.randint(1,10,30) if c[-1]!="0" else np.linspace(1,20, 30) for c in ['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 2']}).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s)

# create a figure with a line per worksheet
wb=xl.load_workbook(f)
fig = go.Figure()
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    if sheet.title != 'Graph':
        df = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name=sheet.title)
        fig = fig.add_traces(px.line(df, x='Unnamed: 0', y='Unnamed: 2').update_traces(name=sheet.title, showlegend=True).data)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks a lot, that works perfectly! One last question: how can I assign different colors to each line?

Comment: reset the line color `update_traces(name=sheet.title, showlegend=True, line_color=None)`