# Python: Plotting lines from excel data in multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, plotly

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets and I would like to print the data using plotly.
For loading the file I use either

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Data.xlsx")
sheets = wb.sheetnames
```

or

```
wb = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
sheets = wb.sheet_names
```

`sheets = wb.sheetnames` works, whereas with `sheets = wb.sheet_names` I get an AttributeError.

Which one should I use and how can I loop over the sheets in order to create a plot out of the data, for example using plotly?
The format of the data in the individual sheets is n times 2, which should result in one curve per sheet.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have previously answered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080449/python-how-to-plot-data-coming-from-different-excel-sheets-in-the-same-chart/71081482#71081482

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much, Rob.