# Plot several lines using plotly express

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-express

I have a dataframe that looks like this, but with 52 columns:

| Day | GOOG | APPL | GE | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 90 | 20 |  |
| 2 | 101 | 95 | 21 |  |
| 3 | 105 | 100 | 19 |  |

I'd like to plot a multiline like this:

[image]

How can I do it for all columns without written column by column:

I'm doing like this:

```
fig = px.line(cart_acum_t, x=cart_acum_t.index, y=[cart_acum_t[cart_acum_t.columns[0]],cart_acum_t[cart_acum_t.columns[1]],cart_acum_t[cart_acum_t.columns[2]]])
fig.show()
```

I've tried this:

```
fig = px.line(cart_acum_t, x=cart_acum_t.index, y=cart_acum_t.columns)
fig.show()
```

But I received this error:

```
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 53, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['index'] is 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a multiple line chart using plotly\_express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822042/how-to-draw-a-multiple-line-chart-using-plotly-express)

Comment: No, it doesn't. My issue is that I have 52 columns and it would be complicated to name all columns like in the example you sent.

Comment: Try using `df.columns`?

Comment: Isn't this what I did in my first attempt?

Comment: Note that the linked thread uses `DataFrame.plot`, which is different from your first attempt.

Comment: You mean to use a different plot tool than plotly express?

Comment: To let pandas use plotly as its backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the index against multiple y-values, you'll probably want to reset the index so it becomes a column, then pass the name of the index to the `x` argument in `px.line`:

```
x_col = cart_acum_t.index.name
cart_acum_t = cart_acum_t.reset_index()

fig = px.line(cart_acum_t, x=x_col, y=cart_acum_t.columns)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I tried and I got this error:
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 58, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['_index'] is 3